# How to fix this Syntax Error in my React App?

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, terminal

i want to deploy my React app to github, i run this command:

```
npm run deploy
```

but i keep getting this error message:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (3:4)

  1 | const reportWebVitals = onPerfEntry => {
  2 |   if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
> 3 |     import('web-vitals').then(({ getCLS, getFID, getFCP, getLCP, getTTFB }) => {
    |     ^
  4 |       getCLS(onPerfEntry);
  5 |       getFID(onPerfEntry);
  6 |       getFCP(onPerfEntry);
```

can you help me solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

it already tells you what the error is

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

what you can do:

```
import {getLCP, getFID, getCLS} from 'web-vitals';

getLCP.then(...your code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `import` the functions/methods at the `top of the file` and then use it.

```
import {getCLS, getFID, getLCP} from 'web-vitals';
```

You can read docs [here](https://web.dev/vitals/)

and then use as

```
const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry) => {
  if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
    getCLS(onPerfEntry);
    getFID(onPerfEntry);
    getFCP(onPerfEntry);
  }
};
```